# How to convert quadkey into tiles coordinates?

Tags: r, tiles, algorithm, bing-maps, quadkeys

I have the quadkey `12022132301033` (zoom level 14). How can I convert itto tileXY or bbox? Eventually, I will plot in in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a pretty straight rewrite of https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile/blob/478e7e1c2291c828e52c381052f108ecec89989b/mercantile/__init__.py#L390

```
quadkey_to_tile = function(qk){

    if(nchar(qk)==0){
        return(list(x=0,y=0,zoom=0))
    }
    xtile = 0
    ytile = 0
    digits = rev(strsplit(qk,"")[[1]])
    for(i in 1:length(digits)){
        digit = digits[i]
        mask = 2**(i-1)
        if(digit == "1"){
            xtile = bitwOr(xtile , mask)
        }else{
            if(digit == "2"){
            ytile = bitwOr(ytile, mask)
            }else{
                if(digit == "3"){
                    xtile = bitwOr(xtile , mask)
                    ytile = bitwOr(ytile , mask)
                }else{
                    if(digit != "0"){
                        stop("Invalid digit ",digit," in quadkey")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return(list(x=xtile, y=ytile, zoom=i))
}
```

I'm sure there's probably a faster and more Rish way to write it but there you go. To adapt this from the python I had to remember R has no `elsif`, remember what the bitwise operator functions were, and remember that R indexing starts at 1.

Here's the more R-ish way:

```
quadkey_to_tile = function(qk){

    if(nchar(qk)==0){
        return(list(x=0,y=0,zoom=0))
    }

    digits = rev(strsplit(qk,"")[[1]])

    i = length(digits)

    masks = 2**(0:(i-1))
    xt = sum(masks[digits=="1" | digits=="3"])
    yt = sum(masks[digits=="2" | digits=="3"])
    
    return(list(x=xt, y=yt, zoom=i))
}
```

It gets the same output as the first version and the python function on your quadkey:

```
> (t = quadkey_to_tile("12022132301033"))
$x
[1] 8619

$y
[1] 5859

$zoom
[1] 14
```

Using the `slippymath` package I get a coordinate for this tile:

```
> slippymath::tilenum_to_lonlat(t$x, t$y, t$z)
$lon
[1] 9.382324

$lat
[1] 45.53714
```

This should be the top-left corner of that tile. I'm not sure quadkeys are rigourously defined so I can't warranty that this is correct for your application.

I've added [a feature request](https://github.com/MilesMcBain/slippymath/issues/16) to slippymath's issue tracker to see if the author wants to add quadkey functions there.

Answer (score 1):

C# version:

```
public static (int z, int x, int y) GetQuadkeyTile(string qk)
{
    var xtile = 0;
    var ytile = 0;
    var mask = 1 << qk.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i < qk.Length; i++)
    {
        mask >>= 1;
        if (qk[i] == '1') xtile |= mask;
        else if (qk[i] == '2') ytile |= mask;
        else if (qk[i] == '3')
        {
            xtile |= mask;
            ytile |= mask;
        }
        else if (qk[i] != '0') throw new Exception($"Invalid quadkey {qk}");
    }
    return (qk.Length, xtile, ytile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presto SQL version from  https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/geospatial.html.

```
ST_Y(ST_CENTROID(BING_TILE_POLYGON(BING_TILE(quadkey_column))))
    AS latitude,
ST_X(ST_CENTROID(BING_TILE_POLYGON(BING_TILE(quadkey_column))))
    AS longitude,
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript Version:
https://github.com/glassonion1/quadkey-tilemath

```
const tileToQuadkey = (
  tileX: number,
  tileY: number,
  zoom: number
): string => {
  const quadkey: number[] = []
  for (let i = zoom; i > 0; i--) {
    let digit = 0
    const mask = 1 << (i - 1)

    if ((tileX & mask) != 0) {
      digit++
    }

    if ((tileY & mask) != 0) {
      digit += 2
    }

    quadkey.push(digit)
  }
  return quadkey.join('')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

postgresql Version:
(translated from sgillies' [mercantile python library](https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile/blob/fe3762d14001ca400caf7462f59433b906fc25bd/mercantile/__init__.py#L465))

```sql
create or replace function quadkey_to_xyz(
    quadkey text,
    out x_tile int,
    out y_tile int,
    out z_tile int) as
$$
declare
    lenQk   int;
    idx     int = 0;
    revQk   text[];
    qkArray text[];
    digit   char;
    mask    int;
BEGIN
    x_tile = 0;
    y_tile = 0;
    z_tile = 0;

    quadkey = TRIM(quadkey);
    lenQk = char_length(quadkey);
    if lenQk = 0 then
        return;
    end if;
    z_tile = lenQk;

    qkArray = regexp_split_to_array(quadkey, '');
    revQk = ARRAY(select qkArray[i] from generate_subscripts(qkArray, 1) as s(i) order by i desc);

    idx = 0;
    foreach digit in array revQk
        loop
            mask = 1 << idx;
            if digit = '1' then
                x_tile = x_tile | mask;
            elseif digit = '2' then
                y_tile = y_tile | mask;
            elseif digit = '3' then
                x_tile = x_tile | mask;
                y_tile = y_tile | mask;
            elseif digit != '0' then
                raise exception 'Unexpected quadkey digit: %', digit;
            end if;
            idx = idx + 1;
        end loop;

    return;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql immutable parallel safe returns null on null input ;
```

```sql
select quadkey_to_xyz('021323323');
-- (109,191,9)
select quadkey_to_xyz('0');
-- (0,0,1)
select quadkey_to_xyz('');
-- (0,0,0)
select quadkey_to_xyz(Null);
-- <null>
select quadkey_to_xyz('12022132301033');
--- (8619,5859,14)
```